Codeception method seeResponseContainsJson returns an error when trying to match data containing Russian letters
My Test:
$I->wantTo("Create new claim");
$I->haveHttpHeader('accept', 'application/json');
$I->haveHttpHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$I->amBearerAuthenticated($I->generateCorrectToken($example['userId']));
$I->sendPostAsJson('/api/claims/', $example['json']);
$I->seeResponseCodeIsSuccessful();
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseMatchesJsonType([
    'code' => 'integer',
    'message' => 'string',
    'status' => 'boolean',
]);
$I->seeResponseContainsJson([
    'code' => 2058,
    'status' => false,
    'message' => 'XML не прошел валидацию',
]);

I get the following error:

Fail  Response JSON does not contain the provided JSON

Expected | + Actual @@ @@ Array ( 'code' => 2058 'status' => false
'message' => 'XML �� ������ ���������'


'message' => 'XML не прошел валидацию' )


How fix that?
PS: codeception/codeception: 4.2.2

The issue could occur because of character encoding mismatches between the JSON response and the JSON string you're passing. Ensure consistent Encoding and the confirm the Server's Response Encoding.
You can try also to use PHP string encoding: ....''message' => mb_convert_encoding('XML не прошел валидацию', 'UTF-8'...
If the problem still remains, debug your response: codecept_debug();

Before asserting, ensure both the expected and actual strings are normalized. Update your test like this:
$I->seeResponseContainsJson([
    'code' => 2058,
    'status' => false,
    'message' => mb_convert_encoding('XML не прошел валидацию', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'),
]);

Alternatively, use PHP's iconv function for stricter encoding checks:

$message = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', 'XML не прошел валидацию');
$I->seeResponseContainsJson([
    'code' => 2058,
    'status' => false,
    'message' => $message,
]);

